# Please show only imported questions, not imported posts under 10k tools

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 10k-tools, recently-imported

Recently, the 10k tools page haved started showing imported posts. Can this be changed to imported questions only ? The redundancy isn't very useful, especially with questions containing large number of answers

[image]

Comment: Can't repro this on Meta Stack Overflow (different page this time, but [the same as last time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73773/problem-on-imported-question-list), as it were). However, Meta Stack Overflow is on version 2011.1.4.3 while Super User is on 2011.1.4.1, so it might have been some change or summat.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73773/problem-on-imported-question-list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SU's now on 2011.1.6.2, and seems to be fine now

[image]